# What is the RPM of the diameter with 16 inches where input shaft RPM is 115.2

Tags: mechanical-engineering

[image]

As given in picture. Using the gearbox and motor rpm of the output shaft of the gearedbox is 115.2 and this shaft is attached to rubber roller whose diameter is 16 inches. So my question is what is the rpm of the 16 inches diameter ?

I want to know 16 inch rubber roll rpm instead of shaft rpm.. The gearedbox input shaft pulley was 8 inches and output shaft was 10 inches. so with 10:1 geared ration it will be: 1440*8/10 = 1152 rpm and 10:1 geared box will convert it to 1152/10 = 115.2 rpm. 115.2 is gearedbox shaft rpm. So it will be rotating 16 inch diameter roller. So will the rpm will get change ?

Comment: why would a a roller turn at a different rate than a shaft that the roller is attached to?

Comment: I want to know 16 inch rubber roll rpm instead of shaft rpm.. The gearedbox input shaft pulley was 8 inches and output shaft was 10 inches. so with 10:1 geared ration it will be: 1440*8/10 = 1152 rpm and 10:1 geared box will convert it to 1152/10 = 115.2 rpm. 115.2 is gearedbox shaft rpm. So it will be rotating 16 inch diameter roller. So will the rpm will get change ?

Comment: this site is not a forum ... if you have anything to add to your question, then do not use a comment ... edit the question at the top of this page

Comment: @Dilip, if the roller pulley rotates at 115.2 RPM and it is attached to the roller, then what will the roller's rotation speed be? How many times will it rotate in one minute?

Comment: @Dilip cut a 10 cm disk from cardboard ... stick a pencil through the middle of the disk ... rotate the pencil at 30 RPM ... does the disk rotate at a different rate?

Comment: So, if shaft size is 3 inches and its roller diameter is 16 inches then rpm of that roller will also be same ? you mean to say